# Debug Angular Tests in with Chrome Headless in Docker Container

Tags: angular, docker, karma-jasmine, headless

I want to debug my Angular test (Jasmine + Karma) running in Chrome Headless under Docker Container.
So I can write better Angular Tests with Debugging enabled for my test files to understand the issue.

Requesting to see any documentation/references on this.

Comment: Running tests in a container is useful for pipelines, not for debugging. Simply run your tests locally to debug them, don't go the extra mile for something useless.

Answer (score 1):

When you kick off the tests, you'll see a message like:

```
[karma-server]: Karma v4.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
```

That's the port that we need to expose. In Docker Compose, it would look like this:

```
    ports:
      - 9876:9876
```

Then you can just go to that URL in your browser.

Bonus points: if your docker host is remote, you can open an SSH tunnel between your machine and docker host like this:

```
ssh -L 9876:localhost:9876 user@your.domain.tld -p 22 -N
```